# Multiple http get and post

Tags: python, post, get, grequests

The task is:

```
1)send an http get to url based on a parameter
2)Modify the response based on the same parameter
3)send an http post to url based on the same parameter
```

I am currently doing this through requests library, but it takes a lot of time to do this one by one and it can be upto 20,000.

I tried `multiprocessing` but for some reason it hangs after sending 5000-10000 get and post.

I read about grequest but it says there
`Order of these responses does not map to the order of the requests you send out.`.I need the order as i have to modify each reponse based on the get i sent.

What is the best option here?I have read about `threading,tornado` too but as i have messed up my first approach with `multiprocessing` i want to be sure before getting onto it again

Comment: Where do you see that the order of the responses does not match the order of the requests? I'm not seeing that on the GitHub page and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502384/are-grequests-responses-in-the-same-order-as-the-requests) contradicts that. Edit: Nevermind, I see that imap does not return them in the same order.

Comment: @PeteyPii that's what m not sure about...is it only for `imap` or `map` as well.Because at the end its written `The API for imap is equivalent to the API for map.`

Comment: Looking at the source seems to suggest to me that map does maintain the same order as the requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that allows you to use grequest's imap (which is theoretically faster than grequest's map function) and know an index to map a response to a request. Credit to a [question asked on the project's GitHub issues](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests/issues/96).

```
from functools import partial

def callback(index, response, **kwargs):
    response.image_index = index

rs = [
    grequests.get(
        url,
        callback=partial(callback, index)
    )
    for index, url in enumerate(urls)
]
```

You should be able to tailor this to suit your needs.

EDIT:
I used this successfully with `hooks`.

```
grequests.get(
        url,hooks={'response': partial(process_response, index)})
```

Comment: So this will not maintain the order but will allow to work with each response and modify it right?

Comment: Yeah, that's how it should work (I have not attempted it myself)