# See what for loop has checked

Tags: python, for-loop, python-requests

I don't really know what to call this issue, sorry for the undescriptive title.
My program checks if a element exists on multiple paths of a website. The program has a base url that gets different paths of the domain to check, which are located in a json file (name.json).
In this current state of my program, it prints 1 if the element is found and 2 if not. I want it to print the url instead of 1 or 2. But my problem is that the id's gets saved before the final for loop. When trying to print `fullurl` I'm only getting the last id in my json file printed multiple times(because it isnt being saved), instead of the unique url.

```py
import json
import grequests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

idlist = json.loads(open('name.json').read())

baseurl = 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/'


complete_urls = []

for uid in idlist:
    fullurl = baseurl + uid
    complete_urls.append(fullurl)

rs = (grequests.get(fullurl) for fullurl in complete_urls)
resp = grequests.map(rs)

for r in resp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    if soup.find('span', class_='actual_persona_name'):
        print('1')

    else:
        print('2')
```

Comment: List `complete_urls` contains all of your URLs. The variable `fullurl` containers only the most recent one.

Answer (score 0):

Since the grequests.map return the responses in order of requests ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502384/are-grequests-responses-in-the-same-order-as-the-requests)), you can match the fullurl of each request to a response using enumerate.

```
import json
import grequests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

idlist = json.loads(open('name.json').read())

baseurl = 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/'

for uid in idlist:
    fullurl = baseurl + uid

complete_urls = []

for uid in idlist:
    fullurl = baseurl + uid
    complete_urls.append(fullurl)

rs = (grequests.get(fullurl) for fullurl in complete_urls)
resp = grequests.map(rs)

for index,r in enumerate(resp): # use enumerate to get the index of response
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    print(complete_urls[index]) # using the index of responses to access the already existing list of complete_urls
    if soup.find('span', class_='actual_persona_name'):
        print('1')

    else:
        print('2')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I undertstood correctly you could just `print(r.url)` instead of the numbers since the `fullurl` is stored inside each response object.

```py
for r in resp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    if soup.find('span', class_='actual_persona_name'):
        print(r.url)

    else:
        print(r.url)
```